# Android get high resolution location info on button press

Tags: android, android-gps

I have read the Android Docs, `FusedLocationProvider` vs `LocationManager`; perused the dizzying array of questions and answers around this topic here in stackoverflow; and developed many tests with poor results so far. Why is this so darned confusing and hard to grasp?

I have an app that needs to get a hi-res Location object (lat/long/alt/accuracy/etc) when the user performs an action in the app; let's say they press a button. What is the best way to do this?

I have used the `fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener()` and get wildly mixed results.

I have used `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`. If I start the GPS Status app on my Galaxy S9 then this produces quite wonderful results. But if that is not running, then the results are worthless.

What am I missing here? Everyone likes to point to this Doc site or that Example site that is mostly worthless and doesn't really answer this specific question. I have wasted hours pouring over those sites that simply don't answer this question. Please, just sum up the general algorithm that should be used here and the calls to make. That is all I need.

I want to be able to walk around in my yard (10 meters here and there) and press the button and have the app show the lat/long/accuracy/altitude/distance-from-last-location and have it be correct every time within a certain level of accuracy. What do I have to do? I need hi-res accuracy, but the ability to notify the user of accuracy less than say 100ft, and still obtain the best accuracy possible even if it has an error of 400ft.

Comment: "Please, just sum up the general algorithm that should be used here and the calls to make" -- generally, what you have sounds about correct, in terms of getting the last known location. However, the last known location may be old or non-existent. So, you might consider requesting location updates, and then react once you get a fix that has a sufficiently high accuracy value.

Comment: Hmmm. I am testing that now and will update after complete. Thx. Going to use FusedLocationProvider for this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing how GPS receivers work.

When there is no app using precise location, all smartphones turn off the GPS receiver to conserve battery power.

Even if you selected location services to be on (in settings), you will notice in the notification bar the icon for GPS use is only present when an app is active, like Google Maps or GPS test app.

Once the receiver is turned on (because some app needs it), it takes some time before a "fix" - accurate location measurement is available.

How long it will take to get a fix depends on several things, including environmental conditions, your phone type, time and distance since last accurate fix, etc.

It may take anywhere from several seconds to sever minutes.

So, what you should do, is subscribe to location as soon as your app is opened, and request to receive it as frequently as possible.

Then, enable the button only once you have good accuracy, and when the button is pressed, show the latest result.

You should probably also display some spinner or message to the user while waiting for accurate fix so the user knows your app is not stuck.

**Edit**: by "subscribe" I mean register the necessary callback so your app will receive the location from the system when it is ready.

How to do this, depends on which API you choose.

There is no error in the google docs.
If you choose to use fused location, you will need to do the following:

- Create a location request object and set priority to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, also `setInterval` and `setFastestInterval` to 1000 (1 second) to get the best accuracy.
- Get a `FusedLocationProviderClient` object from `LocationServices`
- Use the client to register a callback to your app

There are code examples here:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates

In the callback function in your app you can check the accuracy, and if it is good enough for you enable the button and save the location so you can display it to the user when they click the button.

Comment: Yes - you are correct, I must NOT understand how GPS receivers work. Also, big gray area where you say "subscribe to location". Can you please be more specific here about what that is and how I go about waiting/testing for an accurate "fix"? That section in the Android Docs assumes a lot of prior knowledge and especially the section on LocationRequest and LocationSettingsRequest. I have no clue what that is doing. This is the point of this question. Can you provide some stub code that shows what to do?

Comment: There must be an error in this doc page. https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings Especially where it talks about the LocationRequest and LocationSettingsRequest.

Comment: Lev M. You can see my code below. I set Interval to 5000 and fastest interval to 1000. By best accuracy is about 30-40 meters. But, if I open my GPS Status app on my phone, it shows accuracy of 3-5 meters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update. If I set interval to 1000 and fastest interval to 500, I get it down to 10 meters accuracy. Is that the key? What is GPS Status using to get to 3-5 meters?

Comment: @JJJones_3860 location accuracy can fluctuate during the work of you app. Remember - GPS is just a very weak radio signal and some mathematics. Anything can make the signal worse and so location accuracy will be worth. There are many "GPS status" apps, and I don't know what yours is doing, or if it is even accurate. All the parameters are in the `LocationRequest` object. Play with them to see if you can improve accuracy. Also,  a different provider, you can get a list from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager

Comment: Lev M. This is the answer and you explained it well, now that I understand what is going on. Not until I wrote the test code, got it working and then came back and re-read your post did your post make sense. But you are right. It is hard to understand that I need to register and loop and wait for accuracy. And also, if the App has been pushed to the background and the user wakes it up to push the button; I have to wait for accuracy to be obtained again. For novices like me, this paradigm is not intuitive. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - this seems to work. This general flow seems to be the answer.

Assumptions: you are requesting `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in manifest.

Just sample code in the `onCreate()` function of `MainActivity` for testing purposes.

- check to see if we have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission; if not, request.
- get `FusedLocationProviderClient`
- get a start location from `getLastLocation()`; for purposes of comparison and start of track
- define `locationCallback()` to be called by `fusedLocationProvider`; all we are interested in is getting the last one in the stack and save to class Field.
- define `LocationRequest` with interval of 5 secs and `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`
- check to see if the user device is allowing this; not sure what to do with this other than to notify user if not allowed.
- now `requestLocationUpdates` using the `LocationCallback` defined above.
- when user performs action needing current lat/long (e.g. press button), retrieve class field populated with Location object on last `LocationCallback()`.

I am very open to feedback on this pattern. Hope it helps others (as there is a plethora of questions about this). And would love to hear about any problems with this design or issues that I may encounter.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            // getFusedLocationProviderClient
            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            // getStartLocation
            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        StartLocation.set(location);
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            // Define LocationCallback
            locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    if (locationResult != null) {
                        LastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    }
                }
            };

            // Now lets request location updates - that is how this must happen
            // https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Attempt to see if requested settings are compatible with user device.
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
            builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            // Check to see if location settings are satisfied by user's device settings?
            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationTask = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                                // by showing the user a dialog.
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location Settings Are Not " +
                                    "Correct On This Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

            // Request location updates
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
    }
```